# How to fake JavaScript time and timezone in Cucumber tests?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, datetime, cucumber, sinon

In a Rails app, I am trying to write a Cucumber test for a page that displays an event's start time. The time is stored as UTC in the database, while an event.js script that runs on the page computes the local equivalent and appends it to the view.

In the test, I have been trying to use sinon.js to fake the time. A Cucumber step `And I am a user whose local time is "..."` is defined as `page.execute_script "var clock=sinon.useFakeTimers(...)"`. However, this script runs *after* the page loads and after event.js is executed, so the time faking happens too late. If the sinon script is run on a different page first, then by the time the test arrives at the event page, JS time has reverted to its real value.

Secondly, merely faking the time is insufficient for the test. If sinon sets the time to e.g. 2014-07-30T10:00:00+05:00 (i.e. UTC+5), JS computes its equivalent for my actual local timezone. JS gets the timezone info (both the offset and the actual timezone) from the operating system. Thus, it has been impossible to write a Cucumber step such as `And I should see "...GMT+x"` because the "x" always depends on the actual timezone of the system on which the test is being run.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If you're using a library to do the computation for you, you should rely on their tests. From the info you've provided, the test has no value (beside causing you pain) ;-) and can be dropped. But then again, maybe I didn't really get the question...

Comment: There is no library used as JS does an acceptable job of computing local time from UTC and formatting the output string according to locale. The script itself is already thoroughly unit-tested with Jasmine. What I am trying to do is write an acceptance test to demonstrate to the client that a user visiting their site from e.g. Madagascar will see an event's start time in Madagascar's timezone, formatted as per Madagascar standards. And yes, it is causing me pain :)

Comment: I asked a similar question that received an aswer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49504284/stub-browser-time-and-time-zone-with-capybara/49504778#49504778