# Stub browser time and time zone with Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocking, capybara

I have a JavaScript component (e.g. a date picker) that heavily depends on -

1. The current system time
2. The current system time zone

In Ruby and Capybara it's possible to stub any time with the help of libraries such as [Timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop).

Is it also possible to stub these values in the headless browser that Capybara controls?

Thanks!

Edit: Here's an example of how Ruby is stubbed but Capybara's browser still uses the system time

```
before do
  now = Time.zone.parse("Apr 15, 2018 12:00PM")
  Timecop.freeze(now)

  visit root_path

  binding.pry
end

> Time.zone.now
=> Sun, 15 Apr 2018 12:00:00 UTC +00:00

> page.evaluate_script("new Date();")
=> "2018-03-27T04:15:44Z"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you've discovered, Timecop only affects the time in the tests and application under test.  The browser is run as a separate process and completely unaffected by Timecop.  Because of that you need to stub/mock  the time in the browser as well using one of many JS libraries designed to do that.  The one I generally use is `sinon` - http://sinonjs.org/ - , which I conditionally install in the pages `head` using something like

```
- if defined?(Timecop) && Timecop.top_stack_item
  = javascript_include_tag "sinon.js" # adjust based on where you're loading sinon from
  - unix_millis = (Time.now.to_f * 1000.0).to_i
  :javascript
    sinon.useFakeTimers(#{unix_millis});
```

That should work in a `haml` template (adjust if using `erb`) and would install and mock the browsers time whenever a page is visited while Timecop is being used to mock the apps time.

Comment: Thanks! `sinon` works great to mock the *time*, although it doesn't really stub the *time zone* of the browser. To do that, I have to set something like `before(:suite) { ENV['TZ'] = 'America/Los_Angeles' }`, which I tested successfully. The catch is that it has to be before the entire test suite so it can run before the headless browser starts. If I want to run it per test, I need to restart the browser itself. Is there a good way to **restart the headless browser** in Capybara? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @user2490003 not really to restart, but you can use named sessions with  ‘using_session’ to start multiple instances of the browser

Answer (score 5):

I know that the question is a bit old, but we had the same request and found the following solution to work with rails 6:

```rb
context 'different timezones between back-end and front-end' do
        it 'shows the event timestamp according to front-end timezone' do
          # Arrange
          previous_timezone = Time.zone
          previous_timezone_env = ENV['TZ']

          server_timezone = "Europe/Copenhagen"
          browser_timezone = "America/Godthab"

          Time.zone = server_timezone
          ENV['TZ'] = browser_timezone

          Capybara.using_session(browser_timezone) do
            freeze_time do
              # Act
              # ... Code here

              # Assert
              server_clock = Time.zone.now.strftime('%H:%M')
              client_clock = Time.zone.now.in_time_zone(browser_timezone).strftime('%H:%M')
              expect(page).not_to have_content(server_clock)
              expect(page).to have_content(client_clock)
            end
          end
          # (restore)
          Time.zone = previous_timezone
          ENV['TZ'] = previous_timezone_env
        end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a time zone for testing when registering the Capybara driver:

```
  Capybara.register_driver :selenium_remote_chrome do |app|
    options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new

    # Set Chrome to use UTC instead of the computer's timezone.
    options.add_argument('--time-zone-for-testing=UTC')
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

This helps me for usage in pair with [`zonebie` gem](https://github.com/alindeman/zonebie)

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    ENV['TZ'] = Time.zone.tzinfo.name
    # ...
  end
end
```